# Stripslashes doesn't work for my magic-quotes in PHP

Tags: php, magic-quotes, stripslashes

I have started using magic quotes and I have encountered a small problem, an easy problem I guess which I can't figure out.

I wan't to use striplashes which it does not remove when I write something in my textarea

Code:

```
<?php
echo "Removed Slashes: ";
// Remove those slashes
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    echo stripslashes($_POST['question']);
else
    echo $_POST['question'];

?>

<form method='post'>
Question: <input type='text' name='question'/><br />
<input type='submit'>

</form>
```

I also tried this one which actually works!:

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

But now I want to use my input for the website for secutiry reasons

Comment: downvoted ._.'
advice will do instead..

Comment: `"I have started using magic quotes"` [Then stop using them](http://us.php.net/magicquotes) That's the best advice you'll get.

Comment: but I want to try them out, why is that so bad?

Comment: @Alexein Without going into every specific reason why magic quotes are bad.. this should do http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php **"This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0."**

Comment: Read the link. They are depreciated in PHP, so what's the point?

Comment: It's deprecated. We all agreed a long time ago that relying on server settings to escape data for us arbitrarily is a big mistake. We simply mitigate the problem (i.e. turn it off if some idiot turned it on) and have our applications escape characters where necessary. You shouldn't need magic quotes because you are not building up query strings. You can avoid it.

Comment: What you are doing isn't sensible. The downvotes however are slightly unwarranted as this seems a genuine inquiry. -- MQ happen to be more hassle than they are worth. They were originally conceived in PHP2, and not a big security issue back than (meant for msql, not mysql and multi-byte charsets). Nowadays keeping them shut down and using the much simpler parameterized SQL queries is advised. Use a simplified context-specific escaping function for everything else.

Comment: @mario: So I should build my own functions in PHP to avoid errors you mean?

Comment: Sort of. It helps to have a custom `html()` escaping function instead of e.g. carrying around `htmlspecialchars(` parameters. Likewise is using PDO with bound params much simpler than the fugly mysql_ functions and manual escaping. - The point being you need different escaping functions/features for different tasks.

Answer (score 2):

I cant put it any better than this comment by cHao on the [manual page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php#102907)

> The very reason magic quotes are deprecated is that a one-size-fits-all approach to escaping/quoting is wrongheaded and downright dangerous.  Different types of content have different special chars and different ways of escaping them, and what works in one tends to have side effects elsewhere.  Any sample code, here or anywhere else, that pretends to work like magic quotes --or does a similar conversion for HTML, SQL, or anything else for that matter -- is similarly wrongheaded and similarly dangerous.
>
> Magic quotes are not for security.  They never have been.  It's a convenience thing -- they exist so a PHP noob can fumble along and eventually write some mysql queries that kinda work, without having to learn about escaping/quoting data properly.  They prevent a few accidental syntax errors, as is their job.  But they won't stop a malicious and semi-knowledgeable attacker from trashing the PHP noob's database.  And that poor noob may never even know how or why his database is now gone, because magic quotes (or his spiffy "i'm gonna escape everything" function) gave him a false sense of security.  He never had to learn how to really handle untrusted input.
>
> Data should be escaped where you need it escaped, and for the domain in which it will be used.  (mysql_real_escape_string -- NOT addslashes! -- for MySQL (and that's only unless you have a clue and use prepared statements), htmlentities or htmlspecialchars for HTML, etc.)  Anything else is doomed to failure.

Really, take the advice. Don't use them, you won't learn anything useful by trying them out, just forget they ever existed.

Take a look at this article http://www.sitepoint.com/magic-quotes-headaches and this one http://econsultancy.com/us/blog/2663-web-app-security-basics-filtering-input-and-escaping-output for more information.

Comment: thanks alot!! I was informed about magic-quotes in my university but I guess I should leave it ASAP.

And also, any idea what I should do instead?? I'm kinda the PHP noob who wants to learn!

Comment: @Alexein I linked to a couple of articles in the post you may find useful. There's loads of information around about not trusting user input and how to cope with it. A couple of good searches on your search engine of choice should get you going. Also, look at some of the 'related links' on the right side of this page.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's easy to attack but seemingly more effort to help. So here's my attempt at being helpful.

So, you are posting data back to the server and you want to ensure that whatever the user posts back does not end up somewhere that it can act maliciously.

The naive strategy you have adopted it to say ok, I'll sanitise data generically by turning on the magic quoting, which should escape all of the nasties...

However, it doesn't. Your job is to ensure that you use a custom sanitisation strategy when dealing with untrusted data, depending completely on how you use it. A good resource for learning **where** you should allow untrusted data to enter a particular location, and **how** to escape untrusted data can be found at [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.235_-_URL_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_URL_Parameter_Values)

You'll notice that not all locations are suitable for untrusted data, escaped or otherwise. This highlights the fact that to truly implement secure websites you have to consider both **where** untrusted data is going and **how** data is getting there.

This question is more directly focussing on the **how**, because we are considering (and attacking the use of) a generic escaping mechanism. You are implying that turning on magic quotes is a suitable method for escaping data destined to all locations your untrusted data can end up.

Best practice says that actually, you need to use an escaping mechanism that is suitable for the location(s) you intend to use it. As has already been pointed out, the use of [mysql_real_escape_string](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is a popular function which is specific to escaping strings for use in a MySQL query. People do use this mechanism, but the need to manually escape your data with this mechanism is superceded by the correct use of [PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). (Binding your untrusted data to a parameter rather than manually building up query strings).

Other obvious escaping mechanisms include encoding html characters using [htmlspecialchars](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [htmlentities](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and, the more generic quote escaping mechanisms [addslashes](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) and [addcslashes](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php). There are even escaping methods for command line arguments [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) and [escapeshellcmd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)

So you can see that escaping data properly is far less trivial than applying magic quotes to all of your incoming data, and there are often well established mechanisms for escaping data safely depending on the location you intend to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Easy fix to your problem is to create a simple function that you push all your data through if it is going to be touching your DB. Can be modeled as such:

```
function sanitizeString($var)
{

    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = stripslashes($var);

    return mysql_real_escape_string($var);

}//end sanitizeString
```

Comment: That's not useful. That's just throwing some functions at a problem. Much escaping != good escaping. Do it context-aware, not by brute-force.